# To dynamic data using p tag in the same line

Tags: css, angular

I have 2 JSON files called `contacts` and `workers`based on the `workersId` present in `contacts` JSON, I am looping and displaying workers of the particular contact like this:
[image]

Now the issue i am trying to display `workers objects` in a single line like this:

[image]

I am displaying workers objects in **P** tag, I have given css as `display:inline;` still it`s not displaying in the same line:

Below is the component code:

**HTML**

```
<h4>Contacts</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <p><span><b>Name:</b></span> {{contact.name }}</p>
  <span><b>Assigned Workers</b></span>
  <div *ngFor="let workerId of contact.workers">
     <p class="workers">
          {{getWorkerById(workerId)}}
      </p>
  </div> 
    <hr>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from './contacts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  contacts;
  workers;

  constructor(private myService: ContactService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getContacts()
      .subscribe(res => this.contacts = res);
       this.myService.getWorkers()
      .subscribe(res => this.workers = res);
  }

    getWorkerById(workerId) {
      if (this.workers && this.workers.length > 0) {
        for(let w of this.workers) {
          if(w.id === workerId) 
            return w.name;
        }
      }
   }

}
```

**CSS**

```
.workers{
  display:inline;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-mr7asc?file=src/app/app.component.css)**

Comment: Do you want to display the workers in a single line?

Comment: Ya i want display the workers in a single line.

Comment: Try this: ```<div class="workers" *ngFor="let workerId of contact.workers">
      {{getWorkerById(workerId)}}</div>```

Comment: Actually for the `p` tag i am writing some conditions. I should display this function: i,e `{{getWorkerById(workerId)}} ` inside `P` tag only. @mojtabaramezani

Comment: Wait i will give you the exact working link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your new comment

```
<h4>Contacts</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let contact of contacts; let i = index">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>{{contact.name }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Assigned Workers</td>
        <td>
      <div [ngClass]="{'all-workers' : showmore[i]==false }">
        <div *ngFor="let workerId of contact.workers;let j=index">
         <p class="workers" *ngIf="(showmore[i]==false &&j<=1)||showmore[i]==true">
           {{getWorkerById(workerId)}},
           </p>
      </div>
      </div>
       <button *ngIf="contact.workers.length>2" (click)="showmore[i]=!showmore[i]">{{(showmore[i])?"Show less":"Show more"}}</button> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in HTML

```
<h4>Contacts</h4>
<div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <p><span><b>Name:</b></span> {{contact.name }}</p>
  <p><b>Assigned Workers</b></p>
  <span *ngFor="let workerId of contact.workers">
     <p class="workers">
          {{getWorkerById(workerId)}} &nbsp;
      </p>
  </span> 
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Still one more requirement, Now we are displaying the workers on the same line, In this link **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-21h9g4?file=src/app/app.component.html** I have added a button called `show more`  **after clicking that button,need to display  the workers one below the other**

Comment: I have posted an aonther answer for this comment

Comment: Thanks for the answer & response.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change HTML and CSS as below

```
  <h4>Contacts</h4>
    <div class="cust-detail" *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
      <p><span><b>Name:</b></span> {{contact.name }}</p>
      <span><b>Assigned Workers</b></span>
      <div class="all-workers">
        <div *ngFor="let workerId of contact.workers">
          <p class="workers">
            {{getWorkerById(workerId)}} &nbsp;
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
```

and `css`

```
.all-workers{
  display: flex;
}
```

[Demo](https://angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-mr7asc.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Still one more requirement, Now we are displaying the workers on the same line, In this link **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-21h9g4?file=src/app/app.component.html** I have added a button called `show more`  **after clicking that button,need to display  the workers one below the other**

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

`

```
 <p *ngFor="let workerId of contact.workers">
      {{getWorkerById(workerId)}}
  </p>
```

`

Using *ngFor on p tag will do.

[image]

this is your view after applying *ngFor to the p tag

Comment: please share stackbliz link instead of screenshot